# Add User Claim after login or change Claim data based on user choice

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a net core 2.1 project with Identity.

I am trying to use Claims as a way to store some user data, basically some choice they have.

When the user first logs in the option is set from querying the choice and getting the 0 index, but later from a razor page user can change it.

Now I need to flush the Claim data from login time and then insert the new choice.

**Q1. As I change the value in SwitchChoice it gets overwritten by UserClaimsFactory because I am "RefreshSignInAsync" so how do I remove the old Claim and add the new Claim for that user?**

**Q2. Side question, do the below approach does not create claim record in database it only create data in cookies, am I right?**

**Startup.cs is configured:**

```
services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser>, UserClaimsFactory>();
```

**UserClaimsFactory.cs is configured:**

```
public class UserClaimsFactory : UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<AppUser, IdentityRole>
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration;
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UserClaimsFactory(
        UserManager<AppUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> optionsAccessor,
        IConfiguration config,
        ApplicationDbContext context)
        : base(userManager, roleManager, optionsAccessor)
    {
        Configuration = config;
        _context = context;
    }

    protected override async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateClaimsAsync(AppUser user)
    {
        var idx = user.Id;

        List<UserChoise> ret = await _context.UserChoise.Where(s => s.AppUserId == idx)
                                .Include(s => s.InnerChoise).OrderBy(s => s.CDate)
                                .ToListAsync();

        if (ret!=null && ret.Count>0) { 
            var identity = await base.GenerateClaimsAsync(user);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ABC", ret.Count > 0 ? ret[0].Name.ToString() : "NA"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("XYZ", ret.Count > 0 ? ret[0].Phome.ToString() : "NA"));
            return identity;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Login.cs is configured:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
{
    returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {          
        // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
        // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: true);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.Email);

            if (!user.Active)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
                return RedirectToPage("/Index");
            }
            _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
        {
            return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
        }
        if (result.IsLockedOut)
        {
            _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
            return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
            return Page();
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return Page();
}
```

**SwitchChoice.cs is configured:**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    var curUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    var identity = User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
    var existingClaim = identity.FindFirst("ABC");
    if (existingClaim != null)
    identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim);

    var existingClaim2 = identity.FindFirst("XYZ");
    if (existingClaim2 != null)
    identity.RemoveClaim(existingClaim2);


    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ABC", newVal1 != "" ? newVal1 : "NA"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("XYZ", newVal2 != "" ? newVal2 : "NA"));

    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(curUser);

    return RedirectToPage("/Index");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using claims to *store data*. Claims, or more specific IdentityClaims, are supposed to *model the Identity*. Think of claims as Birthday, DriversLicenceNumber, Gender. Claims that do not change frequently.

So the solution is to remove the data from the claims and move it to a store. It may be part of the business context.

Q1: Choices can be saved in a cookie. Save the choice in the (business) context as fallback in case the cookie is deleted.

Q2: The claims are not persisted in the database. It only creates a ClaimsIdentity. The claims are stored in a token or cookie, depending on the scheme.

Comment: Thanks, I am not sure what is this " Save the choice in the (business) context"? are you saying to get the data and create the cookie and check if it exist then do not create from database?

Comment: Yes, you can persist the choice in the database. Use the choice from the cookie or if not available (e.g. value=null)  use the persisted choice value and create a new cookie.

Comment: But you don't have to use a cookie. If you don't want to or can't store it client side then use the value from the database. And you don't have to persist it in the database if a cookie suffices.

Comment: Thanks for this useful tip, but i have moved the logic to database so that it can be persisted after logout also.